# Cannot start service workspace_v6: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task:

Tags: docker-compose, containers, docker-entrypoint

I am trying to compose this docker file but i couldn't do it. everytime I am getting the same error,

```
ERROR: for workspace_v6  Cannot start service workspace_v6: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/home/kowshika/products/dataweave_docker/v6/entrypoint.sh": stat /home/kowshika/products/dataweave_docker/v6/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

This is my docker file,

```
FROM python:2.7.17-slim


RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential -y && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

#RUN apt-get install -y python-mysqldb
RUN apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    && apt-get clean

RUN apt-get install -y procps && apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get install -y curl htop wget
RUN apt-get -y install cron
RUN apt-get -y install mariadb-client
RUN apt-get -y install openssh-client && \
    apt-get install -y lsof && apt install -y net-tools && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnumeric

RUN pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6

WORKDIR /usr/src/dataweave

ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/src/dataweave
RUN echo $PYTHONPATH >/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dataweave_path.pth

COPY ./dataweave_docker/v6/requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r  requirements.txt

# Setting up docker timezone
ENV TZ=Asia/Kolkata
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

COPY ./dataweave_app ./dataweave_app
COPY ./dataweave_precompute ./dataweave_precompute
COPY ./dataweave_reports ./dataweave_reports
COPY ./packages ./packages
COPY ./nordstrom ./nordstrom
COPY ./dataweave_docker/v6/entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh


ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/dataweave/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["dataweave_app/main.py", "dataweave_app/app.cfg"]
```

this is the command which i used to compose,

```
docker-compose -f v6/compose/dev-docker-compose.yml up workspace_v6.
```

Help me get through this.